# Ability to log in when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, android-app

App version: 1.0.20

If you click the link "Start using without an account..." on the home screen and then you click on the icon to ask a question, a dialog box appears saying: "You need an account in order to ask a question." and you have two options: "Cancel" and "Sign up". 
Would it be possible to add "Log in" as a third option or have it "Sign up/Log in" and then you click on "Sign up/Login" you will see an the sign up options, but also the log in options?

I know if you click on the logo in the top left hand corner you can open a menu and "Sign in or log in".